# A question on spectral decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory

I'm working on a quantum information processing question but my question is purely maths based, it regards the spectral decomposition of the following matrix :

Note: I believe (though I may be wrong so correct me if I am) that spectral decomposition is a way to find a diagonalized version of a matrix

Say we have $H=\begin{pmatrix} \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} &\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{pmatrix}$.

Now spectral decomposition of this matrix will be $H=\sum_i \lambda_i|\psi_i\rangle \langle\psi_i|$, where $\lambda_i$ corresponds to an eigenvalue and $|\psi_i \rangle$ is its associated eigenvector.

First we find the eigenvalues :

$Det(H-\lambda I)=Det \begin{pmatrix} \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\lambda &\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\lambda \end{pmatrix}=(\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\lambda)(-\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\lambda)-\tfrac{1}{2}=-\tfrac{1}{2}+\lambda^2-\tfrac{1}{2}=-1+\lambda^2\Rightarrow \lambda=^+_-1$

Now we find the eigenvectors:

$\lambda=1$:

$\begin{pmatrix} x\\y \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} &\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x\\y \end{pmatrix}$

$\Rightarrow \tfrac{x+y}{\sqrt{2}}=x \Rightarrow (\sqrt{2}-1)x=y $

$ \tfrac{x-y}{\sqrt{2}}=y \Rightarrow (\sqrt{2}+1)y=x $

These equations give eigenvectors $v_1=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\(\sqrt{2}-1) \end{pmatrix}, v_2=\begin{pmatrix} (\sqrt{2}+1)\\1 \end{pmatrix} $

The eigenvectors for $\lambda=-1$ are found, similarly, to be $v_3=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\(-\sqrt{2}-1) \end{pmatrix}, v_4=\begin{pmatrix} (-\sqrt{2}+1)\\1 \end{pmatrix}$

But $H=-\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\(-\sqrt{2}-1) \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 &(-\sqrt{2}-1) \end{pmatrix}- \begin{pmatrix} (-\sqrt{2}+1)\\1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} (-\sqrt{2}+1)&1 \end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\(\sqrt{2}-1) \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 &(\sqrt{2}-1) \end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix} (\sqrt{2}+1)\\1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} (\sqrt{2}+1)&1 \end{pmatrix}$

Doesn't give me a diagonal matrix , where have I gone wrong ?

Comment: There's only one eigenvector for each eigenvalue, not two. Your $v_2$ is a scalar multiple of your $v_1$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson ah okay, still though I worked out all  possible combinations of $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$ , as in $ v_1-v_3$ etc and I couldn't find any that give a diagonal matrix

Comment: Since $H$ isn't diagonal, I wouldn't expect any equation that goes $H=\dots$ to yield a diagonal matrix.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think I have misunderstood spectral decomposition , I have done a little more reading since your post could you clarify if I understand it now. We have $H=UDU^T=\sum \lambda_i |v_i><v_i|$, where the D matrix is the matrix with eigenvalues on the diagonal , U matrices correspond to the set of e-vectors $U=(v_1 v_2...)$. We don't always get a diagonal matrix for H, but D is always diagonal and if we wanted to compute any function on H we do spectral decomposition and apply the function to the entries in D , i.e the eigenvalues

Comment: Sounds good to me. This works provided $H$ has enough linearly independent eigenvectors to form a basis. Not every matrix does, and if $H$ doesn't, then there isn't any $U$, nor any diagonal matrix $D$. But maybe the matrices that come up in your area are all diagonalizable, e.g., symmetric matrices are always diagonalizable.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, given the context $H$ will very likely always be a Hermitian matrix. These are always diagonalizable.